# Strange behaviour Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10

I am an Ubuntu noob and after last update I got Ubuntu crashed. I have tried several solutions and finally got an working Ubuntu BUT every time I now start the pc, I get the "low graphics" window and nothing can be done from there.

I fix it by swithing to tty and:

```
sudo jockey-text -e kmod:nvidia_304 #everytime I have to change the driver, if once it is 304, then the next time I have to use for ex 304_updates
sudo killall Xorg
sudo service lightdm start
```

It happens again and again when I start my pc.I have already tried all the existing Nvidia drivers and result is the same.

Any ideas how I can fix it?

My system:

OS: Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit with Gnome 3.10.1
Graphics: GeForce GTX 560/PCIe/SSE2
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz × 4

Comment: I have already tried all the Nvidia drivers (304/319/331) via all possible ways (Software Center as well). Installed/purged/reinstalled/rereinstalled/rerereinstalled. Same issue.

Comment: also works without killing Xorg. First applying a driver, then start LightDM

Comment: I had a similar issue, are you low on disk space? That was what was causing my Low Graphics error. If you are, try deleting some files and restarting.

Comment: No. I have approximately 60Gb of free space =(

Comment: I have built a new Xorg.conf by nvidia-settings. Same issue.

Comment: Have you tried TenPlus1's answer?

Comment: Sure, I have tried, but got the same problem.

Comment: Please don't change the title of the question to indicate your question is answered. Instead, mark the correct answer as such. I invite you to take a short tour on how this site works: http://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution that worked for me. The issue was with Bumblebee.

Switched to tty.

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

Then i have started the X

```
sudo lightdm start
```

After that I've installed the Nvidia 331 driver (using additional drivers tab) and rebooted the system and now it works almost fine. I still get System error windows on start-up, but at least X start itself without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing it the way you normally do, then go into Software Sources and then to the Additional Drivers tab and select nvidia_319 from the list and Apply...  This will install and build the latest nvidia graphics binary and safely remove the old version which seems to be glitching...